# Tableview subtitles on IOS7

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, ios7

I'm trying to add a subtitle to my tableview cells, but they are not displayed.
Where is the mistake?

Is the row
`[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle]`
up-to-date, also with iOS 7?

Best regards

Frank

---

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    if (!cell)
    {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    cell.textLabel.text = @"TestA";
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = @"TestB";

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: That looks correct to me. Did you use Storyboard/Xib file? Make sure you put a cell prototype over there.

Comment: Are you saying that this code only results in the main title being shown but not the subtitle for each row? Is this all in code or do you use prototype cells?

Answer (score 5):

This code:

```
if (!cell)
{
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
}
```

will never execute because `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier: forIndexPath:` is guaranteed to allocate a new cell.

Unfortunately, `registerClass:forCellReuseIdentifier:` doesn't let you specify a `UITableViewCellStyle`.

Change `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath` to simply `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier`.  This method does not guarantee a cell will be returned.*  When it's not, your code will then create a new cell with the style you want.

---

* - (It will if you're using a storyboard, as rdelmar points out, but that's not the case here.)

Comment: "This method does not guarantee a cell will be returned" -- not necessarily true. If the cell was made in the storyboard, that method is also guaranteed to return a cell.

Comment: If you've registered a class or nib with the tableView it will automatically return an instance of it and cell will never be nil.

Answer (score 1):

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath        *)indexPath {
UITableViewCell *cell = nil;
cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell"];
if (cell == nil)
{ 
 cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:@"cell"];
}
cell.textLabel.text = @"Title1"; 

cell.detailTextLabel.text = @"Subtitle 1";

return cell;
}
```

Comment: answers should include a description of the solution.

Comment: Give the cell an identifier from Inspector view and write this code in **cellForRowAtIndexPath**, where **cel.detailTextLabel.text** is the subtitle.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and no solution on the internet worked for me. Turns out I was being an idiot. I'll post my solution just incase someone else experience a similar scenario.

I am assuming that you are using **storyboard**, have created a **prototype** and set the style to **subtitle**

In your storyboards **document outline**, make sure you select the protoptype cell and select the subtitle. See image: 
[image]

Now ensure that the label font colour is of a nature that us visible on your background!

Answer (score 0):

Simply subclass UITableViewCell and override

```
- (instancetype)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier;
```

with the first line being

```
[super initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
```

And register your cell class with the table view

```
[tableView registerClass:[YourCellSubclass class] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"YourCellID"];
```